# SOLR CLOUD - Uploading LTR features

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have a SOLR Cloud cluster with 4 nodes. Collections are created with 4 shards and 2 replicas.

I was using REST endpoints (pointing to a single instance for all operations), to create feature(s) and model(s).

```
http://{{SOLRCLOUD-HOST}}:8983/solr/{{ACTIVE_INDEX_NAME}}/schema/feature-store

http://{{SOLRCLOUD-HOST}}:8983/solr/{{ACTIVE_INDEX_NAME}}/schema/model-store
```

When I execute REST endpoint to fetch the existing feature(s) and models(s)

```
http://{{SOLRCLOUD-HOST}}:8983/solr/{{ACTIVE_INDEX_NAME}}/schema/feature-store

http://{{SOLRCLOUD-HOST}}:8983/solr/{{ACTIVE_INDEX_NAME}}/schema/model-store
```

I see my feature/model created sometimes and the other times it says they don't exist.

At this point, when restart my cluster, thre GET calls always return the created features and models.

Couple of questions -

1. Like config sets, is there a way to upload features and models without using REST endpoint?
2. Is restart required after uploading features and models.
3. Should the feature/mode be executed against all collections in the cluster (assume I have more than one collection with the same data created for different purpose, plz don't ask why, I have them)
4. Are the features/models created available for collections created in the future with the same config set, I ask this question because the feature/model uploaded is seen inside the config set as - _schema_model-store.json and _schema_feature-store.json

Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any answers?
I was stuck with feature-store not being available on all shards. Your suggestion of restarting solr helped. Is that the permanent solution?

To answer your Question #3:
You need to upload the features/models for each collection, since collection is part of the upload url, notice the "techproducts" in [feature upload example from solr doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/learning-to-rank.html#uploading-features):

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:8983/solr/**techproducts**/schema/feature-store' --data-binary "@/path/myFeatures.json" -H 'Content-type:application/json'

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the collection to make the feature and model json file to be available on all shards of the collection. The restart of solr is not required.